# Install Java JRE using System- Level Configuration for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, java

I am installing Java's JRE using a batch script.  The JRE version is jre-8u31-windows-i586.exe.  When I run the script I get the following error:

[image: Install error.]

This is the command line call

```
C:\Users\v-rray\Desktop\jre-8u31-windows-i586.exe INSTALLCFG=C:\Windows\SUN\Java\Deployment\deployment.config AUTO_UPDAT
E=0 WEB_JAVA=0 /l C:\Users\v-rray\Logs\ALLTNH-LYNC01_setup.log
```

I have search event logs looking for any OS issues.
I have tried the following URI File path.

[image: Attempts]

This is the contents of the deployment.config file.

```
#deployment.config file
deployment.system.config=file\:C\:/Windows/Sun/Java/Deployment/deployment.properties
deployment.system.config.mandatory=true
```

I really need some suggestions at this point.

Comment: Please [edit] yout question to include the contents of `C:\Windows\SUN\Java\Deployment\deployment.config`

Answer (score 0):

I got the install to work correctly.  What I did was put the deployment.config file in the C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment directory.  The property in the file was setup as so:

```
deployment.system.config=file\:C\:\\Sup\\Java\\UPGRADE\\Deployment\\deployment.properties
```

The exceptionlist file was in the same directory as the deployment.properties file.